# How to fix ' You either need MANAGE_USERS or CREATE_USERS permission to: getting profiles related to user 0' error?

Tags: android, android-permissions, permission-denied, user-permissions

I search lots of to fix this error but I can't get success. So I post question here.
This error is mainly in Xioami device. Redmi 5A ,Redmi 5 ,Redmi 6A.
I test in Redmi 7A but it is working fine in that.

I have error like:

```
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:2016)
android.os.Parcel.readException (Parcel.java:1962)
android.view.autofill.IAutoFillManager$Stub$Proxy.finishSession (IAutoFillManager.java:575)
android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.finishSessionLocked (AutofillManager.java:1038)
android.view.autofill.AutofillManager.commit (AutofillManager.java:872)
android.app.Activity.onStop (Activity.java:1912)
androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStop (FragmentActivity.java:636)
androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStop (AppCompatActivity.java:184)
android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStop (Instrumentation.java:1376)
android.app.Activity.performStop (Activity.java:7270)
android.app.ActivityThread.performDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:4407)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleDestroyActivity (ActivityThread.java:4468)
android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap5 (ActivityThread.java)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1678)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:106)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:176)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6651)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (RuntimeInit.java:547)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:824)
```

My LoginActivity.java is as below:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);
        StartAppAd.showSplash(this, savedInstanceState,
                new SplashConfig()
                        .setOrientation(SplashConfig.Orientation.PORTRAIT)
                        .setLogo(R.drawable.ic_app_icon)
                        .setMinSplashTime(SplashConfig.MinSplashTime.REGULAR)
                        .setTheme(SplashConfig.Theme.BLAZE)
        );
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equals(getIntent().getAction()) && getIntent().getDataString() != null) {
            PublicMethods.loadFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.ly_container, new RegisterFragment());
        } else
            PublicMethods.loadFragment(getSupportFragmentManager(), R.id.ly_container, new LoginFragment());
        getToken();
    }

    private void getToken() {
        FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getInstanceId()
                .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<InstanceIdResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<InstanceIdResult> task) {
                        if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                            return;
                        }

                        String token = task.getResult().getToken();
                        PrefrencesManage preferenceManager = new PrefrencesManage(LoginActivity.this);
                        preferenceManager.SharePrefrenceBase(preferenceManager.USER_FCM_TOKEN, token);
                    }
                });

    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        new PrefrencesManage(this).clearPrefrences();
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}
```

and my fragment is as so simple like form of login and registration, in that not any permission required except INTERNET.

Please help me to fix this.

Comment: is there any fix for this, i'm also having issues in xiaomi devices

Comment: @NavneetKrishna no

Comment: having the same issue, no idea how to avoid crashed

Comment: Same thing happening with me, any fix anybody ?

Comment: No I don't get any solution for this

Comment: I've met the same issues, anyone know how to fix?